# How can I modify the width of only the last segment of a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

Is it possible to make the last segment a different width?

Something like this? I was thinking endcaps, but I want it to stretch to the second last to the last anchor point. I want something like what I've circled in this picture, but only at the end of my stroke, but I don't think the arrowheads could fulfill this request as I want them bent or curved sometimes. The red arrow thing is suppose to be the end I want.

[image]

[image]

The yellow part in the image is what I'm trying to achieve with the stroke, not manually drawing it in. But the thing I have circled does it for the whole entire line, not just the end. But again, I don't think the arrowheads could do this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Width Tool](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/painting-fills-strokes.html#create_strokes_with_variable_widths) to do this:

[image: variable width stroke in Illustrator]

Select the last anchor with the Direct Selection Tool, then click and drag on the anchor with the Width Tool to taper it.